# Android TimerTask crashes program Fatal Exception time-0

Tags: android, timer, timertask

So I have looked around and saw a few posts on similar things but they all had to do with geolocation things and all I am trying to do is a simple timer. Basically I am using a TimerTask to serve as a countdown from 30 seconds within an activity class. the app crashes every time that the TimerTask is called. for context purposes this is a child activity from a parent that called it using a startActivityForResult call.

```
public class NewLevelActivity extends Activity {

    int time = 30;
    int level = 1;
    TextView text;
    TimerTask task;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.new_level);
      text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newLevelText);
      level = WholettheballoutActivity.level;


      task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
                    time--;
                    //text.setText("Level " + Integer.toString(level)+ " will start in " +Integer.toString(time) + " seceonds." );
                    new Timer().schedule(task,1000);
               }
        };

        new Timer().schedule(task,1000);

   }


   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();

   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
    }




}
```

The logcat shows this

```
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3441)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:586)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:10781)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:10781)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:10781)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:10781)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:257)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:10781)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6052)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2826)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2666)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at org.kizik.WLTBO.NewLevelActivity$1.run(NewLevelActivity.java:43)
01-03 01:08:57.630: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19618):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

which I took to be a problem with trying to set the text of the view, but that is not the case because after commenting out the set text part it still is wrong

Comment: I would try to do a clean build and make sure it downloads okay. I can't count the number of times I thought Eclipse downloaded an apk to my device and I was running old code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to update your UI from a non-UI thread, so to do so you need to put your stuff to update the UI inside the `runOnUiThread()`

```
Activity_name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      text.setText("Level " + Integer.toString(level)+ " will start in " +Integer.toString(time) + " seceonds." );
    }
});
```

Comment: now where do I put this code and how do I work that in to make the counter. The program seems to be crashing and restarting every time I call the TimerTask

Comment: ok, this did fix the UI issue. To make it all work I comented out the new timer inside of the TimerTask and make it a sheduleAtFixedRate and that worked.

Comment: This why i hate `Timers` use `Handlers` they are much more useful part of Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NewLevelActivity extends Activity {

int time = 30;
int level = 1;
TextView text;
TimerTask task;




@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.new_level);
      text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newLevelText);
      level = WholettheballoutActivity.level;


      task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
                    time--;
                    textChangeHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    new Timer().schedule(task,1000);
               }
        };

        new Timer().schedule(task,1000);

   }


   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();

   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
    }

    private Handler textChangeHandler=new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  text.setText("Level " + Integer.toString(level)+ " will start in " +Integer.toString(time) + " seceonds." );
        }
    };


}
```

You cannot modify the ui from a thread..you can do it with the help of a handler

Answer (score 0):

put `yourTaskObj.cancel()` when your task is complete.. eg. `task.cancel();`